# Как переименовать SQLite базу данных?

Tags: sqlite, android

У меня есть заполненная база с названием `first_base` и мне нужно ее пепеименовать в `second_base`. Как это реализовать (если возможно - через Java код)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно переименовать файл базы данных, но сначала убедиться, что подключение к БД закрыто:

Вызвать в activity:

```
private void renameDatabase()
{
    File databaseFile = getDatabasePath("yourdb.whatever");
    File oldDatabaseFile = new File(databaseFile.getParentFile(), "yourdb_old.whatever");
    databaseFile.renameTo(oldDatabaseFile);
}
```

Переименовать саму бд нельзя, нужно копировать данные в новую и удалять старую:
Использовав `SQLiteOpenHelper`, можно использовать метод `createDatabaseIfRequired()` в методах `getReadableDatabase()` `getWritableDatabase()`:

```
private boolean checkOldDatabase() {
    Log.d(Constants.LOGTAG, "OperationDbHelper.checkDatabase");
    File f = new File(DB_PATH + OLD_DB_NAME);
    return f.exists();
}

public void createDatabaseIfRequired() throws IOException, SQLiteException {
    if (!checkOldDatabase()) {
      // сравнивать БД / удалять старую / копировать новую
    }
}
```

Comment: А чем отличается файл базы данных от базы данных? Разве это не одно и то же (ну, по названию)?

Answer (score -1):

Изменить саму бд невозможно, но если нужно копировать данные в новую и удалять старую: Используйте SQLiteOpenHelper,

Comment: ваш ответ содержит фактически краткую выжимку из предыдущего ответа. ни дополнений, ни уточнений, ничего полезного.